# How to read an array with javascript from a form

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

This is the question, I have a form that contains a number (not always the same amount) of inputs. All that inputs are tagged by the name ("qtyv[]") and all have the same id ("qtyv").

I want to sum all the values of that inputs, but I dont know how to get that data with javascript.

Any ideas?

```
Qty 1= <input type="text" id="qtyv" name="qtyv[]" />
Qty 2= <input type="text" id="qtyv" name="qtyv[]" />
```

...

I want to sum the values of all that inputs...

Comment: Post some sample HTML that the javascript would be reading

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code/form that you are trying to tally?

Comment: IDs should be unique within the entire document

Comment: Qty 1= <input type="text" id="qtyv" name="qtyv[]" />
Qty 2= <input type="text" id="qtyv" name="qtyv[]" />

I already have the solution, i ll post it now.

Comment: Perhaps you found the answer in this possible duplicate, among many others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
A loop...

```
var i = 0;
var qty = 0;
while (document.getElementsByName('qtyv[]')[i]){
qty += document.getElementsByName('qtyv[]')[i].value;
i++;
}
```

When i reach to the limit of inputs, that function will return undefined so the while will exit.